# mysql joining to many tables while including a main table

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I'm having trouble because the main table doesn't have the foreign key i'm trying to search by. Rather, the secondary tables have the key I'm searching by. This means I have to build my information in an array, table by table, joining each with the main table to find the data.

transactions is the main table. deposits is joined to transactions, then I get the deposit info from transactions table. same is then done for payments, invoices, etc. It seems like a less-than-ideal way to design it, or maybe i'm missing something.

i am hoping there is a better way to join the tables in one shot rather than joining them all with union joins.

so currently i say

```
select * from transactions T left join deposits D on T.id = D.tID where D.account = '123' 
union 
select * from transactions T left join invoices I on T.id = I.tID where I.account = '123'
union....
```

etc

any better suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Why not also join on the account?

Comment: thanks, the account is a normalized value that I am searching by in the secondary tables. i don't need more account info, just the entries in the primary table, but the only way to get those entries is by joining against the secondary tables, which have the foreign key, the "account ID"

Comment: mind setting up some sample data and schema @ sql fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

i think this should do the work

```
 select * from transactions T 
 left join deposits D on T.id = D.tID and D.account = '123' 
 left join invoices I on T.id = I.tID and I.account = '123'
 .....
```

Comment: Thanks, but what this ends up doing is  making very long rows joining all the deposits and invoices on the same row. What i'd need is the deposit/transaction join result rows to be listed underneath the invoice/transaction results.